# How can I disable the Quill editor

Tags: quill

I have a a template which displays rich text data. When the user clicks edit I turn the template into an editable Quill editor like so:

```
  'click #editNote': (e, t) ->
    note = t.find '.container'
    console.log note
    basicEditor = new Quill(note)
```

Then once the user clicks save I want to be able to disable the Quill editor. How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This isn't currently documented but you can do this:

```
basicEditor.editor.enable(false)
```

Comment: Still works on quilljs.com (the editor variable on the homepage is `quill` not `basicEditor`)

Comment: @jhchen - enable(false) is making the editor.selection.getRange(); to return null. I wanted to have a readonly version of my text with highlighting enabled. I'm using quill 0.20.1

Answer (score 16):

`quill.disable()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

Use this statement

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container');
quill.enable(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set the property
[readOnly]="true"

Example:

`<quill-editor format="html" [readOnly]="true" formControlName="editor"></quill-editor>`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ngx-quill, use this code:

```
@ViewChild('quill') quill: QuillEditorComponent;

this.quill.setDisabledState(true);
```

Work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
let quill = new Quill('#myDiv');
quill.disable();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<quill-editor [disabled]="true"></quill-editor>
```

Answer (score -3):

Getting quill undefined, we need to import ngx-quill in component.